# How Can we swipe only month or day when we click on next or previous button in fscalendar in swift4

Tags: swift4

When I used next and previous button for both month and day when i clicked on month next button it should be swipe only month not day and same as for day please help me...how can I do I am using this code but when I clicked next or previous button both month and dates are swipping I want individual

```
  @IBAction func year_leftbtnAction(_ sender: Any)
{
    print("Clicked")

    calendar.setCurrentPage(getPreviousMonth(date: calendar.currentPage), animated: true)
}

func getPreviousMonth(date:Date)->Date
{
    return  Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .weekOfMonth, value: -1, to:date)!
}


@IBAction func year_rightbtnAction(_ sender: Any)
{
    print("Clicked")

    calendar.setCurrentPage(getNextMonth(date: calendar.currentPage), animated: true)
}

func getNextMonth(date:Date)->Date
{
    return  Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .weekOfMonth, value: 1, to:date)!
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this function to switch any date component in [FSCalendar 2.8.0](https://github.com/WenchaoD/FSCalendar/tree/2.8.0) (with Swift 4.2/Xcode 10):

```
func switchDateComponent(component: Calendar.Component, isNextDirection: Bool) {
    if let nextDate = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: component, value: isNextDirection ? 1 : -1, to: calendar.selectedDate ?? Date()) {
        calendar.select(nextDate, scrollToDate: true)
    }
}
```

Now if you need to select previous/next day you can call `switchDateComponent(component: .day, isNextDirection: false)` or `switchDateComponent(component: .day, isNextDirection: true)`. For the month component it will be similar, just call `switchDateComponent(component: .month, isNextDirection: false)` or `switchDateComponent(component: .month, isNextDirection: true)`.